# How does Cognito GetUser identify user pool & user from an access token without user pool ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito

How does using an access token with Amazon Cognito's GetUser operation determine the user pool and user with only the region and access token, since the token contains all necessary identification information?

i ma trying to get username from access_token with the help of get_user operation